# Unable to get desired background for IcsSpinner

Tags: android, spinner, actionbarsherlock

This is the Spinner Code:

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
    android:id="@+id/mSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg_grey" />
```

**bg_grey** is the light grey color background in the 1st image.

TextView code `dropdown_text.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mDropDown"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_dark_grey">
</TextView>
```

in the Activity:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ,Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity.this, R.layout.dropdown_text, mArray);
```

InActive state of the Spinner:

[image]

This is what i wanted. But,

Active state of the Spinner:

[image]

Why is the background of the DropDown color dark grey. I want it to be light grey as in the 1st image.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the background of your textView to:

`<android:background="@color/bg_grey">`

That doesn't explain why it's dark gray, but will fix it.

I had some similar issue with a ListView, on which the background color of the items were changing randomly. When I changed the background color of the ListView item they stayed as I wanted. Still a mistery to me.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity.this, R.layout.dropdown_text, mArray){

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView tv =  super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                //set your own selector for textview background here
                return tv;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                TextView tv =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                //set your own selector for textview background here
                return tv;
            }

        };
```